# C# - Drag MenuStrip item to ListBox

Tags: c#

I want to allow user to drag any item from MenuStrip to a ListBox.
I did it between to ListBoxes, but can not do it with MenuStrip.
Thanks a lot for your help.

I use WinForms, C#

For the destination ListBox I modified its property
    `this.listBox2.AllowDrop = true;`
and created the following two events:

```
private void listBox2_DragOver(
object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
e.Effect=DragDropEffects.All;
}


private void listBox2_DragDrop(
object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
{ 
    string str= (string)e.Data.GetData(
        DataFormats.StringFormat);            
    listBox2.Items.Add(str); 
}
}
```

What I need is what should be done to the source MenuStrip to allow drag items from it the ListBox, in over words how to make MenuStrip draggable.

Thanks to all for their help.

Comment: Can you post your code? It's easier for people to point out where you have gone wrong.

Comment: What technology for the UI? WinForms? WPF? You need to show us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag Menu Strip Item is the same like `ListBox` item.
Check your code...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
The missing event is that I should add event to ToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown, I prefer to use right click instead of left click to avoid the conflict between ToolStripMenuItem_Click and the drag event, this the code:

```
            AllowDrop = true;

private void tsmi_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            DoDragDrop(sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

Add also this code to the ListView:

```
private void lvAllowDropListView_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {   
        System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem button = e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem))
                       as System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
        if (button != null)
            {
        try
        {
            SmallImageList = sysIcons.SmallIconsImageList;
            LargeImageList = sysIcons.LargeIconsImageList;

            System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem item = e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem))
                       as System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                AddToolStripMenuItem(item.Text, item.Name);
            }
        }
        catch { }
            }
    }
    private void AddToolStripMenuItem(string name, string tag)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem item = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(name);
        int Index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count;i++ )
            if(Items[i].Tag.ToString() == tag)
            {
                Index = i;
                break;
            }
            if (Index == -1)
            {
                item.Tag = tag;
                Items.Add(item);
            }
    }
```